# How do I run npm install node for sass?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTYCI.png)
Anyone know how to fix this error when trying to run npm install node for sass?

tried sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass

error: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

I'm trying to run gulp on a wordpress theme sass and unable to compile it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check you current Node.js version using the following command:

```bash
node --version
```

If the version is under `v12.0.0`, then your going to need to update your Node.js, since `Object.fromEntries()` is not supported in versions before `v12.0.0`